# Task await vs Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await, task

In terms of parallelism are these equivalent?

```
async Task TestMethod1()
{
    Task<int> t1 = GetInt1();
    Task<int> t2 = GetInt2();
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2); 
}

async Task TestMethod2()
{
    Task<int> t1 = GetInt1();
    await GetInt2();
    await t1;
}
```

In `TestMethod2`, I am mainly interested in understanding whether `GetInt1()` starts executing while awaiting `GetInt2()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in terms of "parallelism" (actually *concurrency*), they are pretty much the same.

In particular, the [TAP docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) state that returned tasks are "hot", that is:

> All tasks that are returned from TAP methods must be activated... Consumers of a TAP method may safely assume that the returned task is active

So, your code is *starting* the asynchronous operations by calling their methods. The tasks they return are already in progress. In both examples, both tasks are running concurrently.

It doesn't matter terribly much whether you use two `await`s or a single `await Task.WhenAll`. I prefer the `Task.WhenAll` approach because IMO it more clearly communicates the intent of concurrency. Also, it only interrupts the source context (e.g., UI thread) once instead of twice, but that's just a minor concern.

Comment: Thanks for clarification